# Order of GIS coordinates in Polygon

Tags: gis

I have a sample polygon:

```
POLYGON ((-3.7573242 56.909002300000004, -3.881555000000001 56.552116000000005, -4.4824219 56.6803738, -4.428197900000001 56.3194963, -3.2958984 56.340901200000005, -2.9522632000000004 56.783630800000005, -3.7573242 56.909002300000004))"
```

I've been asked for the NE,NW,SE,SW coordinates ?

Is there a standard order ?

Comment: Nope, could be lat,lon or lon,lat depending on where you expect the polygon to be.

Comment: What I mean is, is the first point NE, second NW etc .., is there any kind of convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the bounding box of the polygon, the imaginary box that contains your polygon. The corners of this box need not be any of the actual points in the polygon.

[image]

So to calculate the SW corner you need to find the minimum of the X and Y coordinates, and for the NE corner you need the maximums.

Comment: So the SW corner would be -4.4824219, 56.3194963 ?